# Interchange values and keys in OrderedDict Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ordereddictionary

Here is my OrderedDict

```
o=OrderedDict([('xmllist', 123), ('A', 124), ('B', 125), ('C', 126), ('D', 127)])
```

How can i interchange its keys and values as ,

```
o=OrderedDict([('A', 123), ('B', 124), ('C', 125), ('D', 126)])
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Best Way to Exchange Keys with Values in a Dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031851/python-best-way-to-exchange-keys-with-values-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: It seems like the question derived from [the answer of the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21746599/2225682). You'd better build desired key, value pair from the beginning. instead of change it later.

Comment: @falsetru Yes ! it is derived from the previous one. Can you please tell me how to build desired key and value pair ?

Comment: @Nishant, The expected result in the question does not agree with the title. It just remove `xmllist` from the dictionary. Is that what you want?

Comment: @falsetru Yes , want to remove `xmllist` from the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> o = OrderedDict([('xmllist', 123), ('A', 124), ('B', 125), ('C', 126), ('D', 127)])
>>> OrderedDict((key1, o[key2]) for key1, key2 in zip(itertools.islice(o, 1, None), o))
OrderedDict([('A', 123), ('B', 124), ('C', 125), ('D', 126)])
```

mapping: `o['A'] = o['xmllist']`, `o['B'] = o['A']`, `o['C'] = o['B']`, ...

Comment: >>> o = OrderedDict([('xmllist', 123), ('A', 124), ('B', 125),
...                  ('C', 126), ('D', 127)])
>>> del o['xmllist']
>>> o
OrderedDict([('A', 124), ('B', 125), ('C', 126), ('D', 127)])

This is what i want but want to make values interchange like , 

o=OrderedDict([('A', 123), ('B', 124), ('C', 125), ('D', 126)])

Comment: No , don't want to subtract `1` from each value , these may not be ordered always !